# Array of arrays in F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I have the following array `CF` which contains arrays. How can I set up another array of same length as `CF` which finds the nth element of arrays within `CF`.

```
let CF=   [|for i in 0..(Connection.Length-1)-> 
                          res RProject.[i] rc.[i] D.[i] in.[i]|]
```

Comment: what is `n`? What abaout ?`res` and `RProject`, `rc`, `D`? ... sorry I have no clue what you are really trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the *nth* element of each array, mapped to a new array. You can do this with `Array.map`.

Here's an example. First, an array of arrays:

```
let a1 = [| [|1; 2; 3|]; [| 4; 5; 6 |] |]
```

Let's say you want the second element in each of these arrays, mapped into a new array. This can be done like this:

```
let a2 = a1 |> Array.map (fun a -> [| a.[1] |])
```

In this example, `a2` will now have the value `[|[|2|]; [|5|]|]`.

Notice that an exception will be thrown if you attempt to access an array index that is outside the bounds of any of the arrays.